# Ordenar con php

Tags: php

Quiero hacer digamos 2 consultas en una, como lo hago?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  * FROM peliculas ORDER BY off_line");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  * FROM peliculas ORDER BY fecha DESC");
```

con el codigo esta claro lo que quiero
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hace el order by que sea dinamico pasandole una variable, o no se si entendi bien pero podes order by [col1],[col2]

Answer (score 1):

La solucion:

Simplemente poner las dos columnas en la misma fila separadas por comas.
La tabla peliculas y
Las columnas son: off_line y fecha

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  * FROM peliculas ORDER BY off_line, fecha DESC");
```

Gracias a Michael Saban

Comment: Lo valioso sería que explicaras como lo hiciste, para que el resto aprenda y no tenga que preguntar se nuevo la próxima vez.

Comment: @Candid Moe hecho

Comment: Si esta es la solución entonces esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada